# C# ModInverse Function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, modulo

Is there a built in function that would allow me to calculate the modular inverse of a(mod n)?
e.g. 19^-1 = 11 (mod 30), in this case the 19^-1 == -11==19;

Comment: Note that you can reverse arbitrary multiplications. For example 2 has multiplicative inverse modulo 30 since GCD(2,30)!=1

Answer (score 22):

Since .Net 4.0+ implements BigInteger with a special modular arithmetics function ModPow (which produces “`X` power `Y` modulo `Z`”), you don't need a third-party library to emulate ModInverse. If `n` is a prime, all you need to do is to compute:

```cs
a_inverse = BigInteger.ModPow(a, n - 2, n)
```

For more details, look in Wikipedia: [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), section [Using Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Using_Euler.27s_theorem), the special case *“when m is a prime”*. By the way, there is a more recent SO topic on this: [1/BigInteger in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181494/1-biginteger-in-c-sharp), with the same approach [suggested by *CodesInChaos*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181821/1879042).

Comment: Please note that it's the special case, *when m is a prime*.

Answer (score 11):

```
int modInverse(int a, int n) 
{
    int i = n, v = 0, d = 1;
    while (a>0) {
        int t = i/a, x = a;
        a = i % x;
        i = x;
        x = d;
        d = v - t*x;
        v = x;
    }
    v %= n;
    if (v<0) v = (v+n)%n;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, but it would be nice if it could signal (e.g. by throwing an exception) if the inverse is impossible (`a` is not invertible modulo `n`) which happens when `a` and `n` shares a non-trivial factor (their GCD exceeds one).

Answer (score 3):

The [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) Crypto library has a BigInteger implementation that has most of the modular arithmetic functions.  It's in the Org.BouncyCastle.Math namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly more polished version of Samuel Allan's [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21919260/11178549). The `TryModInverse` method returns a `bool` value, that indicates whether a modular multiplicative inverse exists for this number and modulo.

```
public static bool TryModInverse(int number, int modulo, out int result)
{
    if (number < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(number));
    if (modulo < 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(modulo));
    int n = number;
    int m = modulo, v = 0, d = 1;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int t = m / n, x = n;
        n = m % x;
        m = x;
        x = d;
        d = checked(v - t * x); // Just in case
        v = x;
    }
    result = v % modulo;
    if (result < 0) result += modulo;
    if ((long)number * result % modulo == 1L) return true;
    result = default;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no library for getting inverse mod, but the following code can be used to get it.

```
// Given a and b->ax+by=d
long[] u = { a, 1, 0 };
long[] v = { b, 0, 1 };
long[] w = { 0, 0, 0 };
long temp = 0;
while (v[0] > 0)
{
    double t = (u[0] / v[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        w[i] = u[i] - ((int)(Math.Floor(t)) * v[i]);
        u[i] = v[i];
        v[i] = w[i];
    }
}
// u[0] is gcd while u[1] gives x and u[2] gives y. 
// if u[1] gives the inverse mod value and if it is negative then the following gives the first positive value
if (u[1] < 0)
{
        while (u[1] < 0)
        {
            temp = u[1] + b;
            u[1] = temp;
        }
}
```