# 1/BigInteger in c#

Tags: c#, biginteger, inverse

I want to make

```
BigInteger.ModPow(1/BigInteger, 2,5);
```

but `1/BigInteger` always return `0`, which causes, that the result is `0` too. I tried to look for some `BigDecimal` class for c# but I have found nothing. Is there any way how to count this even if there is no `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Use something else instead of Integer. How about double?

Comment: Double is too short for division by BigInteger

Comment: How possible `1/BigInteger` returns `0` ?. `BigInters` default value is `0`. It should thrown `DivideByZeroException`.

Comment: From the little I know of El Gamal, I don't think the literal multiplicative inverse is what you're looking for.

Comment: @MartinŠevic Depends on what you want. Suppose your denominator is a `BigInteger` with less than 300 decimal figures, then the division of `1` by the corresponding double works OK. Precision is lost, but magnitude is OK. But with e.g. 400 decimal figures, `double` will over-/underflow to infinity or zero.

Comment: @SonerGönül Well, it should not compile because it doesn't say `new BigInteger()`, neither `default(BigInteger)`. It should complain that a "type" is used like a "variable" in the expression.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen In this case, `BigInteger` doesn't look like a variable. This looks like a class usage.

Comment: @SonerGönül Like I said, it **is** a "type" (it's a `struct` in this case), and therefore it's disallowed to use it **as if** it were a variable.

Comment: Microsoft Solver Foundation has a rational class; if you want to represent exact rational numbers, it's quite useful. You can download it for free.

Answer (score 12):

`1/a` is 0 for |a|>1, since `BigIntegers` use integer division where the fractional part of a division is ignored. I'm not sure what result you're expecting for this.

I assume you want to [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `a` modulo `m`, and not a fractional number. This inverse exists iff `a` and `m` are co-prime, i.e. `gcd(a, m) = 1`.

The linked wikipedia page lists the two standard algorithms for calculating the modular multiplicative inverse:

- [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which works for arbitrary moduli
  It's fast, but has input dependent runtime.

  I don't have C# code at hand, but porting the pseudo code from wikipedia should be straight forward.
- Using Euler's theorem:
  [image: $i^{-1} = i^{φ(n)-1}$]
  This requires knowledge of φ(m) i.e. you need to know the prime factors of m. It's a popular choice when `m` is a prime and thus φ(m) = m-1 when it simply becomes [image: $a^{-1} = a^{p-2}$]. If you need constant runtime and you know φ(m), this is the way to go.

  In C# this becomes `BigInteger.ModPow(a, phiOfM-1, m)`

Comment: You could be right. Note that `i` and `n` must be relatively prime for this to be well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The overload of the `/` operator chosen, is the following:

```
public static BigInteger operator /(
        BigInteger dividend,
        BigInteger divisor
)
```

See [BigInteger.Division Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_division.aspx). If the result is between `0` and `1` (which is likely when `dividend` is `1` as in your case), because the return value is an integer, `0` is returned, as you see.

What are you trying to do with the `ModPow` method? Do you realize that `2,5` are *two* arguments, two and five, not "two-point-five"? Is your intention "take square modulo 5"?

If you want floating-point division, you can use:

```
1.0 / (double)yourBigInt
```

Note the cast to `double`. This may lose precision and even "underflow" to zero if `yourBigInt` is too huge.

Answer (score 0):

For example you need to get d in the next: 
**3*d = 1 (mod 9167368)**

this is equally:
**3*d = 1 + k * 9167368, where k = 1, 2, 3, ...**

rewrite it:
**d = (1 + k * 9167368)/3**

Your d must be the integer with the **lowest** k.
Let's write the formula:
**d = (1 + k * fi)/e**

```
public static int MultiplicativeInverse(int e, int fi)
        {
            double result;
            int k = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                result = (1 + (k * fi)) / (double) e;
                if ((Math.Round(result, 5) % 1) == 0) //integer
                {
                    return (int)result;
                }
                else
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
```

let's test this code:

```
Assert.AreEqual(Helper.MultiplicativeInverse(3, 9167368), 6111579); // passed
```