# C# ModPow -1 problems

Tags: c#, modulo, pow

I was trying this:

```
BigInteger.ModPow(x, -1, z);
```

But this method can't use -1 as Pow argument. Is there any already implemented class in C# that can do that, or I need to make my own class ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ModInverse Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483706/c-sharp-modinverse-function)

Comment: Try `BigInteger.ModPow(x,z-2,z);` instead.

Comment: @ja72 Yes, but it will not work if `z` is not a prime, for example in `BigInteger.ModPow(value: 7, exponent: 60-2, modulus: 60)` which I used as a case in my comment to Hans Passant's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Keep your highschool math book identity in mind: x ^ -1 == 1/x.  So this is simply:

```
  BigInteger.DivRem(BigInteger.Divide(BigInteger.One, x), z, out remainder);
```

Comment: This does not work! We wanted the modular inverse. For example with `BigInteger.ModPow(value: 7, exponent: -1, modulus: 60)` we would like the result ___43___ because 7^(-1) or 1/7 is 43 modulo 60. This is because 7*43 gives 1 modulo 60. Your answer will always fail if `x` is non-trivial, because `BigInteger.Divide(1, x)` is seen as a rational number (between 0 and 1) which will be truncated to zero. So you start by discarding all information about `x`, after which there is no hope we can succeed.