# How can modular multiplication and exponentiation be performed in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, modular-arithmetic

If I know parameter `a`, `k` and `p` then how do I calculate this in C#?

```
s=a*k^-1 mod p
```

Its for cryptographic purpose and I'm new. Please don't feel offended if the question is not appropriate.

Please note that `k^-1` is the modular inverse of `k (mod p)` and not power operator.

Comment: Yes **k^-1** means modular inverse of **k** *mod p). @ArtjomB.

Comment: How big are `a`, `k` and `p`? The question is whether an int would suffice or a BigInteger would be needed.

Comment: `a,k and p` would be as big as `long` variable can take. sorry. @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is about modular inverse, I suppose it will benefit the seeker to look at another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483706/c-sharp-modinverse-function).

Crux of the answer is -

> Net 4.0+ implements BigInteger with a special modular arithmetics function ModPow (which produces “X power Y modulo Z”), you don't need a third-party library to emulate ModInverse. If m is a prime, all you need to do is to compute:

In C# as per [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this is defined as

```
public static BigInteger ModPow(
    BigInteger value,
    BigInteger exponent,
    BigInteger modulus
)
```

Using this we can do something like to calculate inverse of the k modulo p
like

```
BigInteger bi= ModPow(k, -1, p );
int b= (int) bi;
s= (a* bi )%p;
```

Comment: using `ModPow(k, -1, p )` will cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` to be thrown indicating that `exponent is negative`. [BigInteger.ModPow Method Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

Answer (score -4):

public static double DoMath(double a, double k, double p)

```
    {
        return (a * Math.Pow(k, -1)) % p;
    }
```

Comment: `k^-1` is a modular inverse, which is not the same as `Math.Pow(k, -1)`.